# Quaternion identity proof

Tags: group-theory, matrices, complex-numbers

If $q \in \mathbb{H}$ satisfies $qi = iq$, prove that $q \in \mathbb{C}$

This seems kinda of intuitive since quaternions extend the complex numbers. I am thinking that $q=i$ because i know that $ij = k , ji = -k$, which is expand to all combinations of $i,j,k,$ which I think means that I have to use $ijk = i^2 = -1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put $\;q=a+bi+cj+dk\;$ , then

$$\begin{align*}qi=ai-b-ck+dj\\
iq=ai-b+ck-dj\end{align*}$$

Well, what do you deduce about the coefficients $\;a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R\;$ above?

Answer (score 1):

let $q=a+bi+cj+dk = (a,b,c,d)$ so

$$
qi = (-b,a,d,-c) \\
iq = (-b,a,-d,c)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Any complex number $q$ satisfies $q i = i q,$ so it is not true that $q=i$ However, just writing $q = a + b i + c j + d k,$ and writing down $q i$ and $i q$ ought to do the trick.

Comment: sorry, Igor, our answers "crossed in the post"

Comment: @DavidHolden some things are just too hard to resist :)